# how to create directory in oracle home

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, directory

I need to create an oracle directory in oracle installation folder. In my case this path is `D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1`. I tried `create directory ora_dir as '\'`, but this make reference to `D:\`.
Is there any way to create the directory pointing to oracle_home?

Regards.

Comment: I'm not sure that information is easily available within the database - it's kind of irrelevant to the running processes, and especially to clients. How will you be creating the directory - by running an SQL\*Plus script on the server, say? If so you could pas the environment variable as a positional parameter, perhaps?

Comment: Hi, @AlexPoole. I need to create the directory in a valid path(inside oracle instalation folder, dbhome) from a procedure using this line `execute immediate q'[CREATE or replace DIRECTORY DIRECTORY_DIR AS 'ORACLE_HOME']';`. This procedure can be deployed in any database, so, the goal is that directory take the oracle home path of that database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're already doing this dynamically from a procedure, you could get the ORACLE_HOME environment variable (as it was set when the instance started anyway) via a Java call, but you need a separate function:

```
create or replace function getenv(name varchar2) return varchar2
as language java
name 'java.lang.System.getenv(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
/

create or replace procedure p42 as
begin
  execute immediate q'[CREATE or replace DIRECTORY DIRECTORY_DIR AS ']'
    || getenv('ORACLE_HOME') || q'[']';
end;
/
```

Assuming both compile OK, when executed the directory is created with the path from the environment variable:

```
exec p42;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

select directory_path
from all_directories
where directory_name = 'DIRECTORY_DIR';

DIRECTORY_PATH
----------------------------------------
/dboracle/orabase/product/11.2.0
```

If your procedure is in a package, the function can be in there too, privately if you prefer. And you don't need any additional privileges to use the Java call, just `create procedure`, which you already have in this case.

Unfortunately this doesn't work in Windows as [ORACLE_HOME is set in the registry, not the environment](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47798/intro.htm#NTDBI2641); it may be possible to [get information from the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java) but you may also have more than one Oracle Home so you'd have to determine which registry key to use.

There is also (as Aramillo found) an [undocumented] built-in [`DBMS_SYSTEM` package](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_system.html) that can provide the same information; with that you could do:

```
create or replace procedure p42 as
  l_oracle_home varchar2(100);
begin
  dbms_system.get_env('ORACLE_HOME', l_oracle_home);
  execute immediate q'[CREATE or replace DIRECTORY DIRECTORY_DIR AS ']'
    || l_oracle_home || q'[']';
end;
/
```

But you would need to have execute permission granted on that package, and it's undocumented status might give you pause; some of the functionality seems to be restricted to SYSDBA anyway (note 159968.1).

While poking around My Oracle Support looking for `DBMS_SYSTEM` references, I also stumbled over this option:

```
select nvl(substr(file_spec, 1, instr(file_spec, 'lib') -2),
  substr(file_spec, 1, instr(lower(file_spec), 'bin') -2)) as oracle_home
from dba_libraries
where library_name='DBMS_SUMADV_LIB';
```

... which apparently also works on Windows, but you need sufficient privileges to see the data dictionary entries.

Comment: Hi, alex. This could be a solution, but give me null directory path for DIRECTORY_DIR, and as you said this should work as well in windows. (`select getenv('ORACLE_HOME') from dual;` -- this is returning null)

Comment: @Aramillo - maybe the environment variable isn't set when Oracle starts as a service? I don't know... sorry, somehow I've never run Oracle on Windows.

Comment: Problem is i don't set ORACLE_HOME environment variable in my system, so, looks like in windows this is not necessary, not as well in linux, where seems to be a requirement. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Aramillo - I guess it's [set in the registry, not the environment](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47798/intro.htm#NTDBI2641), and accessing that [looks tricky](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java); plus you could have multiple homes defined so I don't know how you'd know which is correct, perhaps. Not something I'm able to play with, sorry. It was a nice idea...

Comment: Yes, that's could be possible, if you had multiple homes you wouldn't know which you want, now i'm little confusing ggg. I'll keep looking to see what i find

Comment: Hi Alex, please take a look at this procedure dbms_system.get_env [here](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_system.html). Seems to be other solution. Thanks

Comment: @Aramillo - nice, and much simpler, as long as you have permission to execute it. (The Java one only needs `create procedure`, which you already have). You should probably add that as a new answer, and I might then remove this one. Does that work for the Windows registry settings too?

Comment: Please if you can add this to your post, will be better, and the asnwer will be complete.

Comment: And, i don't know if this will works if there are oracle_home environment variables defined, in my case don't give troubles because i don't have one.

Comment: @Aramillo - OK, I've added that, and another method I found while investigating that. Thanks. Can't help thinking you deserve most of the credit for this though... *8-)

Comment: That query works great to, i think that together we got a better answer. Thanks for all. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the full path:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY ORA_DIR AS 'D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1';
```

Comment: Yes, @tilley31, this works but i need this to be generic,if oracle were installed in C partition or by Admin user instead of Administrator the path will be like `C:\app\Admin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1`

Comment: I don't think it's possible with SQL, you would have to use a shell. I see you're in Windows, so I can't help with that.